# Access token valid across multiple servers

Tags: oauth-2.0, load-balancing, access-token, sugarcrm

how can i make my access token valid across multiple servers?

So here's the scenario:

We have an SugarCRM application installed behind a load balancer with a round robin configuration. We're using oauth acces token for 3rd party vendor authorization in our CRM. The 3rd party vendor is sending multiple requests to CRM using the same token. The problem is that the token that is generated from app server 1 is only valid in app server 1. Any requests using the same token and sent to app server 2 will become invalid.

Comment: How are your validating your access token in your Resource server?  Are you using any libraries sich as jwt.io to validate your tokens?